# Validate the data from a Json File

Tags: citrus-framework

I got this error message while trying to execute the `get` method.

```
Validation failed: Values not equal for element '$..userName', expected 'admin' but was '["admin",null,"HiCitrus","Unisys1","dscsc"]'
```

This is the script I have used:

```js
 http().client(todoClient)
       .send()
       .get("/rest/api/user/allusers")
       .contentType("application/json");                 

 http().client(todoClient)
       .receive()  
       .response(HttpStatus.OK)     
       .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
   //  .validate(path, controlValue);
       .validate("$..userName","admin");"
```

There are multiple parameters available for the username - is there a way to validate if I find the username "Admin"? Tried with the code below, but it's throwing an error.

```js
.validate("$..userName",contains("admin"));
```

Comment: could you please give the json message payload as it is given to the receive operation? that would help to understand how the json path expression should look like. thx

Comment: Thanks Chris for the Quick Response, I got the Work Around for it.

Comment: It brings me the luck -> .validate("$..userName","@contains('ForDemo')@");